# Copy values of a column into an array in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pass the values of column in an array and then use it in a loop but the issue is that the loop replaces all the values of original column to the first value of array.

E.g here is the original dataset

```
Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
2         5       0      1
3         1       13     1
4         1        0     0
```

The result I want is

```
Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
1         5       0      1
1         1       13     1
1         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
2         2       6      1
2         5       0      1
2         1       13     1
2         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
3         2       6      1
3         5       0      1
3         1       13     1
3         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
4         2       6      1
4         5       0      1
4         1       13     1
4         1        0     0
```

But using my code I'm getting the results like

```
Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
1         5       0      1
1         1       13     1
1         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
1         5       0      1
1         1       13     1
1         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
1         5       0      1
1         1       13     1
1         1        0     0

Score   Col1    Col2    Col3
1         2       6      1
1         5       0      1
1         1       13     1
1         1        0     0
```

This is the code I'm using it's quite simple

```
df_arr = df1['Score'].values
for i in df_arr:
    df1['Score'] = i
    print(df1)
```

However if I add duplicate column of 'Score' e.g 'Score1' and use it in making array and in loop I get the right results.

```
df_arr = df1['Score1'].values
    for i in df_arr:
        df1['Score'] = i
        print(df1)
```

Edit: What I want is for each value in my array i get the dataset in which the first whole column replaced by that array value. I have provided sample as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DeepSpace I have edited the question. Also I have provided sample data of the results I'm getting and the results I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I'm pretty sure this is what you want.  It creates a deep copy of the dataframe so it doesn't end up copying the changes to the original dataframe object.

```
df = df[["Score", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]]

df_list = []
for score in df["Score"]:
    new_df = df.copy()
    new_df["Score"] = score
    df_list.append(new_df)

for temp_df in df_list:
    print(temp_df.to_string(index=False), "\n")
```

Output (Note: I changed the order per OP's request):

```
Score Col1 Col2 Col3
   1    2    6    1
   1    5    0    1
   1    1   13    1
   1    1    0    0 

Score Col1 Col2 Col3
   2    2    6    1
   2    5    0    1
   2    1   13    1
   2    1    0    0 

Score Col1 Col2 Col3
   3    2    6    1
   3    5    0    1
   3    1   13    1
   3    1    0    0 

Score Col1 Col2 Col3
   4    2    6    1
   4    5    0    1
   4    1   13    1
   4    1    0    0
```

Comment: Yes that's right but I need the last column in this case like 'Score' to be the first column in actual case. Anyway to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary containing all your dataframes using a dictionary comprehension. The advantage is that you have all your dataframes nicely organized in a dictionary.

```
df_dict = {'Score_'+str(i): df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']].assign(Score=i) for i in df.Score.unique()}
```

Then, you can access each dataframe as you would any dictionary. For instance, to get the dataframe where `Score` is 2, you can use:

```
df_dict['Score_2']

   Col1  Col2  Col3  Score
0     2     6     1      2
1     5     0     1      2
2     1    13     1      2
3     1     0     0      2
```

You can also see all the dataframes that have been created by looking at the keys of your dictionary:

```
>>> df_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['Score_1', 'Score_2', 'Score_3', 'Score_4'])
```

Comment: looks good, but I want a generic case as the above data is just sample data, I have around 800 rows and 9 columns in actual dataset

Comment: This strategy would still work, just apply it to the columns that you want

Comment: Or use f-strings, `f'Score_{i}'`.